# iToast Alternatives in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm used to iToast library while working in objective­C to display toast but it is not available for swift.

I search on google and find these this.

https://github.com/devxoul/JLToast

both are required to install cocoa pods dependencies.

But I don’t want to install cocoa pods.

Any suggestion for alternatives.?

thanks.

Comment: You can import objective-c files by simply using a bridge header. Usually it takes just one step.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying [DTIToastCenter](https://github.com/dtissera/DTIToastCenter-Swift)? It's written in pure Swift and works pretty well. As for your installation concerns, just drag and drop the source files into your project.